# Copy or migrate tables from MySQL database to Oracle 11g and vice versa using Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I apologize if the question has been asked before, I tried using google and have read quite a few answers on stackoverflow but none were as specific as mine.

So, What's the issue? well, i've got this project in python and one of things I would like to implement is copying tables from one database to another, with all its constraints and what not.

As for the things that I have tried, i've tried using etlalchemy but it's not available for windows. I've thought about saving the tables in pandas dataframes and using to_sql but i'm not sure of the fidelity of the copies.

I've thought about sqlalchemy and alembic but haven't really found a tutorial on how to do it.

As for the database systems i'm using. I've got MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE and Oracle 11g installed on my computer.

Basically I want to copy or migrate tables with all their keys, constraints etc.. from one database to another using Python 3.x. Thank you for your time.

This is the code i'm working with:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
import MySQLdb
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import sys

mySQLConn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost 
                     user="user",         # your username
                     passwd="pass",  # your password
                     db="sakila")        # name of the data base

#dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('user', '1521', service_name='XE')
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost', '1521', service_name='XE')
myOracleConn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'user', password='pass', dsn=dsn_tns) 

#conn = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:1521/?service_name=servicename')

class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df.copy()

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.ix[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

#class usefulDatabaseFunctions():


#    emptyDatabase = ""

    #def getMySQLTables:



class usefulFunctions():

    def connectToMySQL(self): 
        window.label.setText("Connected to MySQL")
        window.setStyleSheet('QLabel#label {color: Green}')
        #cur = db.cursor() 
        #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM actor")
        #print(cur.fetchall())

    def disconnectMySQL(self):
        mySQLConn.close()
        window.label.setText("Disconnected from MySQL")
        window.setStyleSheet('QLabel#label {color: Red}')
        print("Disconnected")

    def connectToOracle(self): 
        window.label.setText("Connected to Oracle")
        window.setStyleSheet('QLabel#label {color: Green}')
        #cursorOracle = myOracleConn.cursor()
        #cursorOracle.execute("SELECT * FROM countries")
        #print(cursorOracle.fetchall())

    def disconnectOracle(self):
        window.label.setText("Disconnected from Oracle")
        window.setStyleSheet('QLabel#label {color: Red}')
        myOracleConn.close()

#    def clearWork(self):  
#        window.queryTextEdit.setText("")
#        window.resultsTextEdit.setText("")
#        window.tableView.clearSpans()
#        window.tableView.clear()

    def executeMySQLUserQuery(self):
        userQuery = window.queryTextEdit.toPlainText()
        cursorMySQL = mySQLConn.cursor()
        cursorMySQL.execute(userQuery)
        print(cursorMySQL.fetchall())
        df = pd.read_sql(userQuery, con = mySQLConn)
        print(df.to_string())
        #txtQueryResults = df.to_string()
        txtQueryResults = str(cursorMySQL.fetchall())
        window.resultsTextEdit.setPlainText(txtQueryResults)
        model = PandasModel(df)
        window.tableView.setModel(model)

    def executeOracleUserQuery(self):
        userQuery = window.queryTextEdit.toPlainText()
        cursorOracle = myOracleConn.cursor()
        cursorOracle.execute(userQuery)
        print(cursorOracle.fetchall())
        df = pd.read_sql(userQuery, con = myOracleConn)
        print(df.to_string())
        #txtQueryResults = df.to_string()
        txtQueryResults = str(cursorOracle.fetchall())
        window.resultsTextEdit.setText(txtQueryResults)
        model = PandasModel(df)
        window.tableView.setModel(model)

    def clearWork(self): #Functie de stergere 
        window.queryTextEdit.setText("")
        window.resultsTextEdit.setText("")
        window.tableView.clearSpans()


#    def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):

    def exitProgram(self): #Functie de iesire
        window.deleteLater()
        window.close()
        window.destroy()


uf = usefulFunctions


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('Proiectv3.ui', self) # Load the .ui file

        self.connectMySQLButton.clicked.connect(uf.connectToMySQL)

        self.disconnectMySQLButton.clicked.connect(uf.disconnectMySQL)

        self.connectOracleButton.clicked.connect(uf.connectToOracle)

        self.disconnectOracleButton.clicked.connect(uf.disconnectOracle)

        self.executeMySQLButton.clicked.connect(uf.executeMySQLUserQuery)

        self.executeOracleButton.clicked.connect(uf.executeOracleUserQuery)

        #self.transferButton.clicked.connect(uf.migrateMySQLToOracle)

        self.clearButton.clicked.connect(uf.clearWork)

        self.exitButton.clicked.connect(uf.exitProgram)

        self.show() # Show the GUI


#app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) # Create an instance of QtWidgets.QApplication
app = QCoreApplication.instance()
#app.setStyle('Fusion')
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui() # Create an instance of our class
app.exec_() # Start the application
```

**Edit 1**

These are solutions that I have tried.

```
def migrateMySQLToOracle(self): #<-- Easieste solution and works.
    dst = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/xe')
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM actor'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, mySQLConn)
    df.to_sql('actor', dst,if_exists = 'replace')


def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):
    # create engine, reflect existing columns, and create table object for oldTable
    #print('Test1')
    srcEngine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@localhost/classicmodels') # change this for your source database
    srcEngine._metadata = MetaData(bind=srcEngine)
    srcEngine._metadata.reflect(srcEngine) # get columns from existing table
    srcTable = Table('offices', srcEngine._metadata)

    # create engine and table object for newTable
    #print('Test2')
    destEngine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/xe') # change this for your destination database
    destEngine._metadata = MetaData(bind=destEngine)
    destTable = Table('office', destEngine._metadata)
    #print('Test3') 
    # copy schema and create newTable from oldTable
    for column in srcTable.columns:
        #print('Test4')
        destTable.append_column(column.copy())
        destTable.create()


def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):
    src = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@localhost/classicmodels')
    dst = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/xe')
    meta = MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=src)
    tables = meta.tables

    for tbl in tables:
        data = src.execute(tables[tbl].select()).fetchmany()
        if data:
            dst.execute(tables[tbl].insert(), data)


def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):
    print('Test1')
    src = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@localhost/classicmodels')
    dst = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/xe')
    meta = MetaData()
    tables = meta.tables;
    print('Test2')
    for tbl in tables:
        print ('##################################')
        print (tbl)
        print ( tables[tbl].select())
        data = src.execute(tables[tbl].select()).fetchall()
        for a in data: 
            print(a)
        if data:
            print (tables[tbl].insert())
            dst.execute( tables[tbl].insert(), data)

def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):
    src = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@localhost/classicmodels')
    dst = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/xe')
    meta = MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=src)
    tables = meta.tables
    for tbl in tables:
        data = src.execute(tables[tbl].select()).fetchall()
        if data:
            dst.execute(tables[tbl].insert(), data)        

def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):
    old_base = automap_base()
    old_engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@localhost/classicmodels", echo=True)
    old_base.prepare(old_engine, reflect=True)
    TableOld = old_base.classes.table_old
    old_session = Session(old_engine)

    new_base = automap_base()
    new_engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/xe", echo=True)
    new_base.prepare(new_engine, reflect=True)
    TableNew = old_base.classes.table_new
    new_session = Session(new_engine)

    # here you can write your queries
    old_table_results = old_session.query(TableOld).all()
    new_data = []
    for result in old_table_results:
        new = TableNew()
        new.id = result.id
        new.name = result.name
        new_data.append(new)
    new_session.bulk_save_objects(new_data)
    new_session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've reviewed some of the solutions that i've originally tried. I have come to the conclusion that there are 2 ways in copying a MySQL table to Oracle.

## First Solution

```
def migrateMySQLToOracle(self):
        src = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<pass>@localhost/<database>')
        dst = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://<user>:<pass>@localhost:port/<service>')
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM <table>'
        df = pd.read_sql(sql, src)
        print(df)
        df.to_sql('<Table name that will appear in Oracle>', dst,if_exists = 'replace')
```

First solution requires importing pandas and using pandas

## Second Solution

This one, technically speaking is more satisfactory, only problem I noticed is that if you want to apply this solution in copying a table from Oracle to MySQL it will have trouble with the NUMBER data type from Oracle and the python console will output an error. Otherwise it kinda does work, just make sure there isn't a NUMBER data type column in the table.

https://www.slideshare.net/Stiivi/python-business-intelligence-pydata-2012-talk

Use this link and start from slide 35. It requires using sqlalchemy